Is there a way to upload an image to Nodejs app?
I write a project with Nodejs. When I try to upload an image on the app from my computer, it uploads to the public/images folder and database but it does not exist on the app. And there is no error on the console or computer. I added Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy and Cors in the index.js folder but it is still the same.
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./post.css";
import { MoreVert } from "@mui/icons-material";
import axios from "axios";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { format } from "timeago.js";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import React from "react";

export default function Post({ post }) {
  const [like, setLike] = useState(post.likes.length);
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const PF = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_FOLDER;
  const { user: currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLiked(post.likes.includes(currentUser._id));
  }, [currentUser._id, post.likes]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(`/users?userId=${post.userId}`);
      setUser(res.data);
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [post.userId]);

  const likeHandler = () => {
    try {
      axios.put("/posts/" + post._id + "/like", { userId: currentUser._id });
    } catch (error) {}
    setLike(isLiked ? like - 1 : like + 1);
    setIsLiked(!isLiked);
  };
  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="postWrapper">
        <div className="postTop">
          <div className="postTopLeft">
            <Link to={`profile/${user.username}`}>
              <img
                className="postProfileImg"
                src={
                  user.profilePicture
                    ? PF + user.profilePicture
                    : PF + "person/noAvatar.png"
                }
                alt=""
              />
            </Link>
            <span className="postUsername">{user.username}</span>
            <span className="postDate">{format(post.createdAt)}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="postTopRight">
            <MoreVert />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="postCenter">
          <span className="postText">{post?.desc}</span>
          <img className="postImg" src={PF + post.img} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="postBottom">
          <div className="postBottomLeft">
            <img
              className="likeIcon"
              src={`${PF}like.png`}
              onClick={likeHandler}
              alt=""
            />
            <img
              className="likeIcon"
              src={`${PF}heart.png`}
              onClick={likeHandler}
              alt=""
            />
            <span className="postLikeCounter">{like} people like it</span>
          </div>
          <div className="postBottomRight">
            <span className="postCommentText">{post.comment} comments</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


import { useContext, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./share.css";
import { PermMedia, Label, Room, EmojiEmotions } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

export default function Share() {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const PF = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_FOLDER;
  const desc = useRef();
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newPost = {
      userId: user._id,
      desc: desc.current.value,
    };
    if (file) {
      const data = new FormData();
      const fileName = Date.now() + file.name;
      data.append("file", file);
      data.append("name", fileName);
      newPost.img = fileName;
      console.log(newPost);
      try {
        await axios.post("/upload", data);
      } catch (error) {}
    }

    try {
      await axios.post("/posts", newPost);
    } catch (error) {}
  };
  return (
    <div className="share">
      <div className="shareWrapper">
        <div className="shareTop">
          <img
            src={
              user.profilePicture
                ? PF + user.profilePicture
                : PF + "person/noAvatar.png"
            }
            alt=""
            className="shareProfileImg"
          />
          <input
            placeholder={"What's in your mind " + user.username + "?"}
            className="shareInput"
            ref={desc}
          />
        </div>
        <hr className="shareHr" />
        <form className="shareBottom" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <div className="shareOptions">
            <label htmlFor="file" className="shareOption">
              <PermMedia htmlColor="tomato" className="shareIcon" />
              <span className="shareOptionsText">Photo or Video</span>
              <input
                style={{ display: "none" }}
                type="file"
                id="file"
                accept=".png,.jpeg,.jpg"
                onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
              />
            </label>
            <div className="shareOption">
              <Label htmlColor="blue" className="shareIcon" />
              <span className="shareOptionsText">Tag</span>
            </div>
            <div className="shareOption">
              <Room htmlColor="green" className="shareIcon" />
              <span className="shareOptionsText">Location</span>
            </div>
            <div className="shareOption">
              <EmojiEmotions htmlColor="goldenrod" className="shareIcon" />
              <span className="shareOptionsText">Feelings</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button className="shareButton" type="submit">
            Share
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./post.css";
import { MoreVert } from "@mui/icons-material";
import axios from "axios";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { format } from "timeago.js";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import React from "react";

export default function Post({ post }) {
  const [like, setLike] = useState(post.likes.length);
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const PF = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_FOLDER;
  const { user: currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLiked(post.likes.includes(currentUser._id));
  }, [currentUser._id, post.likes]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(`/users?userId=${post.userId}`);
      setUser(res.data);
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [post.userId]);

  const likeHandler = () => {
    try {
      axios.put("/posts/" + post._id + "/like", { userId: currentUser._id });
    } catch (error) {}
    setLike(isLiked ? like - 1 : like + 1);
    setIsLiked(!isLiked);
  };
  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="postWrapper">
        <div className="postTop">
          <div className="postTopLeft">
            <Link to={`profile/${user.username}`}>
              <img
                className="postProfileImg"
                src={
                  user.profilePicture
                    ? PF + user.profilePicture
                    : PF + "person/noAvatar.png"
                }
                alt=""
              />
            </Link>
            <span className="postUsername">{user.username}</span>
            <span className="postDate">{format(post.createdAt)}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="postTopRight">
            <MoreVert />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="postCenter">
          <span className="postText">{post?.desc}</span>
          <img className="postImg" src={PF + post.img} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="postBottom">
          <div className="postBottomLeft">
            <img
              className="likeIcon"
              src={`${PF}like.png`}
              onClick={likeHandler}
              alt=""
            />
            <img
              className="likeIcon"
              src={`${PF}heart.png`}
              onClick={likeHandler}
              alt=""
            />
            <span className="postLikeCounter">{like} people like it</span>
          </div>
          <div className="postBottomRight">
            <span className="postCommentText">{post.comment} comments</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


I tried to upload an image from my computer to the app but it did not exist. It existed in the folder and database.

#1 Do you have 2 different git repositories: api (nodejs)   and web (react) ? #2 What do you mean by: "does not exist on the app?" is react failing to show the image? #3 Just to try, hardcode the image url directly in the  and share the results

Yes I have api and client sides. #2 I mean, I cloned the Facebook and when I try to share a post with image, It does not appear on timeline. It looks who and when shared it. The img container is empty. But public/images folder and database contains the img.

If image is well persisted (disk and database), there is no required to show the persistence code. Share only the react side and try the proposed # 3

I tried the #3 issue but it did not work. But thanks for suggestion.

If it doesn't work even with hardcoded image url, react is the problem. Inspect the browser and share us the error

When I inspect the browser, it says "(failed)net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB" next to the uploaded image.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813514/how-to-solve-cross-origin-read-blocking-corb-issue-with-an-aws-lambda-gateway  and or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77358280/err-blocked-by-orb-with-puppeteer, can you debug your app and show the headers of the request which handles the upload ?

share us the hardcoded  section and what is your base url? localhost:3000  ?

@JRichardsz ' <img className="postImg" src={PF + post.img} alt="" />' my image section is this. And yes my base URL is localhost:3000.

@Luuk I couldn't fix it with those solutions but thank you.

#1 According to your description, the problem is not with the upload, is with the visualization of image, right? #2 Are you using pure react (cra) or a mix of  backend + fronented in one repository? #3 Share the react versions os, node version #4 Try with other browsers. Sometimes you get some useful warning in the console #5 Using this repository add your , a folder with the image and try to reproduce the error

Yes, exactly. I use react(cra) and node version is v20.12.2, react version is 18.3.1. How can I try the other browsers? and I do not get the #5

And on the react side, my .env file includes "REACT_APP_PUBLIC_FOLDER = http://localhost:8800/images/" localhost:8800 is api side.
